# Line Price Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

please help me. I have a Wordpress store with a Woocommerce plugin.   In the product catalog, there is an underlined line under the price. How to remove it?

I searched for information on the Internet, found nothing. I think I need to change the CSS code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eJ4d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. I think it will help someone

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price ins,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .price ins,
.woocommerce div.product span.price ins,
.woocommerce div.product p.price ins,
.woocommerce #content div.product span.price ins,
.woocommerce #content div.product p.price ins,
.woocommerce-page div.product span.price ins,
.woocommerce-page div.product p.price ins,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product span.price ins,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product p.price ins,
.product-price ins,
.woocommerce ul.cart_list li .quantity ins,
.woocommerce-page ul.cart_list li .quantity ins,
.woocommerce ul.product_list_widget li .quantity ins,
.woocommerce-page ul.product_list_widget li .quantity in {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with CSS. That underline is text decoration. Your CSS should be

```
.class-name{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

For more information, please [contact me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/akash-halder-801604243/).
https://www.linkedin.com/in/akash-halder-801604243/

Comment: not worked this code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inspect to find the price and see what class it is, then give it nothing like the code below and that's it.

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: not worked this code

Comment: You have to select the class or ID of that text and if it doesn't work, assign the !important value